# Is "Monthly Comic Alive" manga magazine available in English?

Tags: merchandise

I know the Japanese version can be found at [MediaFactory's official site (Japanese)](http://www.mediafactory.co.jp/comic-alive/index.php), but I did not see any reference to an English version.

Is *Monthly Comic Alive* also available in English?

Comment: What makes you think there would be an English version?

Comment: You won't find any, fan sub is the best you can find.

Comment: Is there a specific series you want to read? If so we might be able to point you somewhere where you can read it in English. Unfortunately Shonen Jump is pretty much the only magazine in English.

Comment: I do not know, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy the Japanese version of Monthly Comic Alive from JList (e.g. [here](https://jlist.com/aap474) is the April 2015 issue) or Tokyo Otaku Mode (e.g. [here](https://otakumode.com/shop/560a30bbf481efcf51411fa4/Monthly-Comic-Alive-December-2015) is the December 2015 issue). JList used to also sell subscriptions to some of the manga magazines. If you live in a large city you might also have a Japanese bookstore somewhere (e.g. [Kinokuniya](http://www.kinokuniya.com/us/index.php/fho003)) that sells the magazine in Japanese.

To my knowledge, there is no English release for Comic Alive; this [list of manga magazines published outside Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_manga_magazines#Published_outside_Japan) has no entry for it. Manga are almost always published in English as tankoubon, outside of Shounen Jump and [Yen Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen_Plus). Nowadays some sites, like Crunchyroll, simulpublish individual chapters as they come out.

Here's what I would do: figure out which specific few series in Comic Alive you are interested in following. Chances are you don't care about every last series ever published in this magazine, so identify the ones you do care about. Figure out if they have an English language release (Wikipedia and Anime News Network are pretty good for this, but if you're stumped you can post another question here asking about it.)

If there is an English release, it will probably be tankoubon volumes, or maybe simulpub if you're lucky. If you absolutely must follow your chosen series chapter by chapter, every month, and it's not simulpublished, then find scanlations for it. Then either buy the magazine in Japanese, or buy the tankoubon volumes in English when they come out. If you really don't want the books, you can probably donate them to a public library. (Apparently [public libraries will even stock Monster Musume no Iru Nichijou nowadays](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/the-mike-toole-show/2016-02-07/.98430).)

I know it's not a great solution if you were looking to follow more than two or three series, especially if you don't care about the retouched art and better quality paper in the tankoubon. But unless you read Japanese it's about all you can do. Most likely, simulpub will become more popular as more of the Japanese magazines move online, but for now this is what we're stuck with.